# Vite - How to do custom tree shaking

Tags: svelte, rollup, vite

I'm trying to make a vite plugin that takes already parsed svelte files and creates a "virtual module" (url: `[file_name]?ssr_meta`) for them, but I can't find a way to select the four named exports each page can have (`ssr`, `hydrate`, `router` and `prerender`) and remove any other exports/code that is not related to them.

Is there any way to do this besides manually walking through the AST?